# C# Regex contain []

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex to validate that a string input contains letters with in a length of 6 to 20 and inside the string exists square brackets with an integer.
Something like:

ABC[15]WHATEVER

I get that it would be better to check for the string length without the the use of regex, but still wandering for the brackets with the integer.

What I managed to do:

```
\[([0-9\-]+)]
```

which is working by testing through [regex tester .net](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Is this the appropriate solution though?

Any help is welcome

Comment: It's overcomplicated. `\[[0-9]+\]` would do as well. If the minus sign must be allowed, you should probably only allow it at the beginning: `\[-?[0-9]+\]`. If the group is required (because you want the value) that's `\[(-?[0-9]+)\]`. While escaping the final bracket is optional here, do it anyway, it's easier to parse for human readers when grouping things.

Comment: You need to provide more concrete examples of what will and what **will not** match. For example, is `[1234]` a match? There are six characters and a number within brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with

```
^(?=[\w\[\]]{6,20}$)[A-Z]+\[\d+\][A-Z]+$
```

see [this working example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8b7pdy/4)

### Explanation

1. `^` Begin of string
2. `(?=[\w\[\]]{6,20}$)` Followed by a string between 6 and 20 characters long (`{6,20}`) containing only alphanumeric characters (`\w`) and brackets (`\[\]`), followed by the end of the string (`$`)
3. `[A-Z]+\[\d+\][A-Z]+` the actual pattern - 1 or more digits in brackets surrounded by characters
4. `$` end of string

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment but I don't have the rep. Consider this an expansion on Jeroen's comment.

A length check and regex to match the bracketed integer won't necessarily guarantee a legitimate string. What if there are two bracketed integers? What if the 'letters' prior to the brackets contain an invalid character? I'd recommend a string length check followed by something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\[[0-9]+\][a-zA-Z]+$
```

Which will further constrain the match. Add capturing groups as needed.

Comment: I would change the `+` for `*` for the letters, so that the brackets can be at the beginning or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `string.Length` and regex (`^[a-zA-Z]+\[-?\d+\][a-zA-Z]+$`) to test the completeness.